# OpenCL ridiculous CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, nvidia

My CL program:

```
constant double LATTICEWEIGHTS[19] = { 1.0 / 36.0,

                                      .....

                                      1.0 / 36.0 };

void
computeFeq(
  double  density,
  double3 velocity,
  double* feq) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 19; ++i) {
    feq[i] = LATTICEWEIGHTS[i];         // Line 1
    //feq[i] = 2.0 * LATTICEWEIGHTS[i]; // Line 2
  }
}

__kernel void
Kernel(){

  .....

  double  density;
  double3 velocity;
  double  feq[19];

  computeFeq(density, velocity, feq);
}
```

This code works.
But if I comment Line 1 and uncomment Line2, the CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES will occur immediately.

Any ideas?

I test it with NVIDIA GTX 670M.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does seem wrong, but some things to check first: register usage.  Nvidia GPUs support a verbose output option.  Pass that to clBuildProgram and then check the build log.  Something like this:

```
clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, "-cl-nv-verbose", NULL, NULL);
```

This is documented under the [cl_nv_compiler_options](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/nv/cl_nv_compiler_options.txt) extension.  Lookup the maximum number of registers for your device in the CUDA documents.  What could be happening is that the total number of registers required by a block of work items is more than is available in a single SM/SMX, resulting in the error.

If register usage is not the problem, then it could be an out of bounds memory access somewhere.  I no that the error message does not suggest this, but I have experienced such errors before.  Such an error could be anywhere and is much harder to find.